# Copy text from one file to another using Java

Tags: java, file-io

The content of `Testing.txt` is not getting copied in `Testing2.txt`. If I store some random data in `Testing2.txt` it gets erased when i run the java project instead of copying the content of `Testing.txt`.

Here is the link to the [tutorial I am practicing](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaIO/article.html). The steps are strictly followed and I have named the project, package and classes as it is given.

Why is the content not getting copied?

Comment: Please paste your code. Are you sure you are not holding any xlock to the file being modified?

Answer (score 2):

Both in reading and writing there is missing:

```
} finally {
    writer.close();
}
```

As:

```
public String readTextFile(String fileName) {
    String returnValue = "";
    FileReader file;
    String line = "";
    try {
        file = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
                    try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            returnValue += line + "\n";
            }
                    } finally {
                        reader.close();
                    }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("File not found");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("IO Error occured");
    }
    return returnValue;

}

public void writeTextFile(String fileName, String s) {
    FileWriter output;
    try {
        output = new FileWriter(fileName);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(output);
        writer.write(s);
                    writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: And there is one more thing i discovered while testing i.e if i run the application keeping Testing.txt blank file then ideally Texting2.txt should remain blank, but there was a small vertical rectangular character instead which when i pasted here changed to "ਠ"  .  Now why is this rectangular character coming

Comment: That's Gurmuki letter TTHA (?). Are you sure that the original file is empty (not some End-of-File char)? Properties of file 0B not 0KB.

Comment: yes, i checked again there is no End of File char and file is absolutely blank, and the character that appears is not "TTHA" it is a small rectangular box of the size of the normal character and when i copy-paste it in stack over flow it changes to THAA, may be due to different encoding style or compatibility reasons. and i think it represents a

Comment: it represents a new line character as it appears at the place where i have pressed a enter(to write in next line) in Testing.txt .  i seriously don't know how to get rid of this rectangular boxs in Testing2.txt

Comment: A character rectangle may be a character not existing in the font used. Please check that the read `file.getLength() == 0`, because I am still not ensured. Most unlikely, but manually editing might add an end-of-file sign (Ctrl-Z, Ctrl-D). It might also enter a BOM-character in front of the file (marker for Unicode variants, zero-width space).

Comment: all right, probably it seems a BOM character only, and fyi: the most interesting thing it does not even get pasted in google, and gets pasted as THAA in stack overflow. Any ways thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Close your writers and readers after the operation, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You `FileWriter` object overrides the data written to your file.
Try using this constructor, which appends the data:

```
FileWriter

public FileWriter(String fileName,
                  boolean append)
           throws IOException
```